# [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Assert Query caught Query_abort exception

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, etl, netezza

I'm running a heavy query on RedShift with multiple joins. I'm continuously getting the following error (running via SQL Workbench):

> Amazon Invalid operation: Assert Details:
>   -----------------------------------------------   error:  Assert   code:      1000   context:   dex < m_num_colflds && dex >= 0 -
>   m_num_colflds:1 dex:4   query:     162544   location: 
>   tbl_trans.hpp:398   process:   padbmaster [pid=1572]
>   -----------------------------------------------;

I even searched for this error, but couldn't get to the root cause. But when i query the stl_error table, i get the following information.

> Query 162511 caught Query_abort exception
>   dex < m_num_colflds && dex >= 0 - m_num_colflds:1 dex:4

We have migrated a sample data of about 2.5 TB from Netezza to RedShift and trying to run Netezza ETL queries on RedShift. I have done the necessary conversions. We have a RedShift cluster of 2 nodes and node type is ds2.xlarge. Can someone highlight, what could be the cause?

[Here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vTQpiceOvqsRfxzi4N2eH6ZZfg6BlfaJ1AiT78Pa20jiDvritJc4mFSJFeXzL-mXHZKTDHoSThkJ0aW/pub) is the query

Comment: please post the query. doesnt matter how big.

Comment: Updated question.

Comment: I recommend that you reformat you code into a large number of CTE's, that is, every sub-query would be instead converted into a cte. That will NOT fix the problem but it makes it possible to test the query up to each point which will hopefully identify where the issue is occurring.

Comment: I have virtually the same error, similar type of query (generated by MicroStrategy?)  Did you ever find an answer?

Comment: I didn't find the answer. But that's most probably due to the Redshift limitation on Number of columns involved in joins.

Comment: Did it work well when you resize the cluster to a bigger one? I have the same problem, it works for me when I scaled up the number of nodes